# What link is this 4-rose?

Tags: knot-theory

I am trying to identify the following 4-rose link[image]

Snappy is not able to identify it.

Do you know the answer?

Comment: It is called Borromean rings, it is generally specific for $n=3$ rings, here it's for $n=4$ https://mathcurve.com/courbes3d.gb/borromee/borromee.shtml

Comment: @zwim, the 4-rose link is not brunnian.

Comment: If you know all this stuff already, what do you ask for exactly ?

Comment: I believe it is the torus link $(4,4)$.  Try to make write down the braid word for it and see if it fits the format specified on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus_knot#Properties).

Comment: @N.Owad,  you are right.  It is (4,4) torus link.  Many thanks.